Using checksum tokens with FormBuilder
I've been trying to get a checksum token working with FormBuilder on WordPress but I can't get the format of the URL to work. I know in the FormBuilder UI it tells you what link to use for including the id in the link:
https://example.org/civicrm/renew-your-membership/#?Individual1=123 but it's not prefilling the form (which is set to current user) and security is set to User-Based.
Is there anything specific I should check for under permissions?
I've searched the forums and the web but I can't find any examples or documentation.

Does it have to be a checksum or could you use the message tokens that come with FormBuilder (via 'Expose to' - 'Message tokens')?

There are new tokens as of 5.79.0 - see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/wikis/CiviCRM-v5.79-Form-Token-Notice

Here is what works for me :
In formbuilder, where the name of the form is Test :

Permissions : anyone, including anonymous users
tick "Provide email tokens"


Then in civimail, I use the following token (I choose it in the drop down list of tokens available in civimail GUI)
{afform.afformTestLink}

interesting - but in my first attempt to follow this instruction, i see nowhere that it offers "provide email token" even after changing all the other settings to match your screenshot. civi 5.78.2

there are now some better instructions at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4462#note_172996
